# Where are type aliases in assembly metadata?

Tags: f#, assemblies, metadata, type-alias

The docs are clear that type aliases are not present in MSIL. However, they must be present in the assembly metadata since they're usable from other F# assemblies. Where is this information?

Comment: My guess is in some sort of F# specific metadata which seems to be what is implied by the docs - `Type abbreviations are not preserved in the .NET Framework MSIL code. Therefore, when you use an F# assembly from another .NET Framework language, you must use the underlying type name for a type abbreviation.`

Comment: Uh huh...the question is: where is it?

Comment: Found [this](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/64420#685087) but haven't yet made out where type abbreviations are coming from.

Comment: If you have a look at a dll, the aliases are being encoded in the dll files, as `alias name` `tab` `target name`, but I couldn't figure out where in the compiler source this was coming from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this information is included in a signature data resource within the assembly - you can use the FSharp.PowerPack.Metadata assembly to reflect over it.

Comment: I noticed that in Reflector, but was hoping for confirmation. Thanks.